# Windows 10 mobile, change status bar color

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
```

I attempted the above method, but I am getting this error:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228508.aspx

** Edit **
Found the issue, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/317ed159-75e3-4f8d-a8b7-2e70a5c68bfb/uwp10-how-to-change-statusbar-color-on-phone-and-the-title-bar-on-pcs?forum=wpdevelop
It's a matter of adding the "Microsoft Mobile Extension SDK for Universal App Platform" extension to the C# project references.

Answer (score 5):

Add the refernce of `Microsoft Mobile Extension SDK for Universal App Platform` in your project. You can find it under Reference Manager -> 1. Windows Universal -> 2. Extensions.

[image]

You can change TitleBar for Windows and the StatusBar for Mobile like that:

```
//windows title bar      
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(100,230, 74, 25);
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 230, 74, 25);
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;

//StatusBar for Mobile

if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
{
    Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 230, 74, 25);
    Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().BackgroundOpacity = 1;
    Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
}
```

---

Hope this is helpful to someone.

Reference - [Change title bar and status bar color on WUP](http://www.developerinsider.in/2016/03/13/change-status-bar-color-on-uwp/)

Comment: Thanks. Those adding of references got me too! Couldn't find the `Windows.UI.ViewManagement` before.